# Seating arrangement - How do i pick only the neighbors combinations

Tags: python, python-itertools

i used itertools.combinations to list all possible combinations of a list...but how do i pick only the neighbors so that the users are all together

```
list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
occupied = [2,6,7,11]
```

remaining seats are available... Now how do i arrange two folks together always in the available seats..

```
1 0
3 4
5 0
0 8
9 10
0 12
```

the right combinations are `(1,3) (3,4) (3,5) (8,9) (9,10) (10,12)` (since its two folks..we can interchange them.. so two possible ways)... altogether at the moment i have 28...how do i remove the rest..any guidance would be appreciated
/**********just added my code*********/
import numpy as np
import itertools
from itertools import permutations, combinations, combinations_with_replacement

def seatingarrangement (arr):
arry = arr.split(',')
larr = [int(x) for x in arry]

```
total = (larr[0])
occ = larr[1:]  
     
totals = [x+1 for x in range(0,total)]
print(totals)

for val in totals:
    if val in occ:
           item= totals.index(val)
           totals[item] = 0
print(totals)
```

#result = list(filter(lambda x: x!=0, totals))
result = [x for x in totals if x != 0]
print(result)

```
comb = combinations(result,2)
data = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x < 5, [3, 12, 7, 1, -5])
print(list(comb))

avl = []

#total there are 8 seats and two users are to be seated next to each other always ...  #moreover the seats are not all consecutive

for i,x in enumerate(totals):
    if (i+1)%2 == 0: 
        print('even#:',i+1,'is :',x) 
        data = itertools.dropwhile()
        print(data)
    else:
        print('odd#:',i+1,'is :',x)
```

Comment: Can you share your tries ? [edit] your post and add your code

Comment: i added the code .

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a method that verifies the validity of a pair, regarding the occupied list and the position

```
def is_pair_valid(pair, occupied_list):
    # check occupied
    x, y = min(pair), max(pair)
    if x in occupied_list or y in occupied_list:
        return False
    # check neighbours
    diff = y - x
    return diff in (2, 1, -2) if x % 2 == 1 else diff in (2, -1, -2)
```

- odd number : the other should be at distance `+2, +1 or -2` (ex `3` with `1,4,5`)
- even number : the other should be at distance `+2, -1 or -2` (ex `4` with `2,3,6`)

Then

```
values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
occupied = [2, 6, 7, 11]

for p in filter(lambda x: is_pair_valid(x, occupied), combinations(values, r=2)):
    print(p)
```

Gives the correct

```
(1, 3)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(8, 10)
(9, 10)
(10, 12)
```